# How can I make more than 3 dropdowns in shopify?

Tags: shopify

I want to do more then 3 dropdowns in shopify menu how can I do it ?

[image]

Comment: Can you at least post the picture in English so people can read what has been tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add more than 3 levels. Shopify [`linklist`](https://shopify.dev/docs/api/liquid/objects/linklist) object allows up to 3 levels only.

[image]